# Client Object Model - document library icons

Tags: client-object-model, file-icons

I'm using client object model in a custom webpart.
What I'm looking for is a way to get the file-icons that represent the doc types of the files in a document library.

Probably I need a solution similar to SPUtility.MapToIcon but in client object model.

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corresponding Javascript option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee658997.aspx

and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.maptoicon.aspx (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll or Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashish. That's exactly what I was looking for.